# WP action hook prefix in php class

Tags: wordpress

Hi I'm currently writing my first Wordpress Plugin in OOP way. I have question about naming class methods that will be used in add_action or add_filter. Does calling it `array($this, 'my-action-method)` will suffice to avoid naming collisions or I have to add some prefix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using **$this**, it points to the instantiated object. The method name is just be the object (class) method name. There wouldn't be name collision issues (other than within the object/class itself for which PHP should throw an error).

Comment: Thanks for quick help!